# Can't install mysqlclient on Windows64

Tags: python, mysql, pip, mysql-python, python-wheel

I am using windows10 64bit, python 3.8.2 and unable to install mysqlclient/mysql via pip3, it asked me to download Microsoft Visual C++ 14.00 something, which I did but got a new error after.
I did some research and tried manually download the .whl file and still unable to install.
Because I need to `import MySQLdb`
I tried `pip3 install mysql-python or install mysqlclient` didn't end up well.

```
  _mysql.c
  _mysql.c(42): fatal error C1083: Unable to open: “config-win.h”: No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.25.28610\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

When I manually install .whl file, I get this error

```
$ pip3 install mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl
ERROR: mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 20.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\python38\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Although I can install mysql.connector since I am using `import mysql.connector` in my other projects, I have no idea why I can't install MySQL or mysqlclient, I know there are similar questions to mine, but I didn't find a solution from other posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ERROR: mysqlclient-1.4.6-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

You have 32-bit Python. With it you cannot install 64-bit wheel (`amd64.whl`). Download 32-bit wheel.

Or replace your Python with 64-bit Python and reinstall all packages.

Comment: Thanks dude, I went to download and pip3 installed x32 version, works!!!!

Answer (score 1):

use the regular

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
```

or

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

both will install the actual 1.4.6 version of it.

But you have to have python x64 installed

*Windows x86-64 executable installer* on https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/

I Visual Studio code installed teh x86 version, which couldn't install it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, man, I fixed it by install x32 version mysqlclient package